# using variable on T_OBJECT_OPERATOR php

Tags: php, soap, foreach, stdclass

Basically im trying to parse an stdClass object heres the code I use:

```
while($row = $data->fetch_assoc()){
            try{
                $products = $client->product_by_category_web_list($row['category_id'] , true, '', '2013-01-01', 0, 1500);
            }catch(SoapFault $e){
                echo "No Products under this Category";
            }


            $i = 0;

            foreach($product as $products->item){

                $cat_id = $row['category_id'];
                $id = $product->$i->id;
                $name = $product->$i->name;
                $desc = $product->$i->descrShort;
                $descLong = $product->$i->descrLong;
                $avail = $product->$i->availableToSell;
                $deliverable = $product->$i->deliverable;
                $itemWeight = $product->$i->itemWeight;
                $typelkp = $product->$i->typeLkp;
                $stkbrandid = $product->$i->stkBrandId;
                $dataVatId = $product->$i->dataVatId;

                $query = "INSERT INTO `products` (`product_id` , `product_name` , `product_short_desc` , `product_long_desc` , `product_available , product_deliverable` , `product_item_weight` , `type_id` , `brand_id` , `vat_id`) 
                VALUES (? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?)";

                $stmt = $mysql->prepare($query);

                $stmt->bind_param("isssiiiiii" , $id , $name , $desc , $descLong , $avail , $deliverable , $itemWeight , $typelkp , $stkbrandid , $dataVatId);

                $stmt->execute();

                $mctp = "INSERT INTO `products_categories` (`product_id` , `category_id` , `row_updated`)
                VALUES (? , ? , ?)";

                $match = $mysql->query($mctp);

                $match->bind_param("iii" , $id , $cat_id , 0);

                $match->execute();

                $i++;
            }


        }
```

the Soap Call returns this:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["item"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#3 (10) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(79493)
      ["name"]=>
      string(34) "Claud Butler Phobos Kids Bike 2014"
      ["descrShort"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["descrLong"]=>
      string(1269) "
This year we have worked harder than ever to offer you a great range of quality junior bikes. All exclusively designed and tested in the UK with todays young riders and the popularity of cycling foremost in our minds.


A great bike is the key to a positive riding experience, enjoyment and reliability can be the largest factors when considering your new bike and with over 130 years of design and manufacturing experience we have become the brand of family cycling. Bikes have very much become a fashion item and we believe the kids choices are as important as Mum and Dads so we have a vast range of eye catching models to choose from. We also offer alloy and steel framed models to suit all budgets while maintaining great quality and performance at great value.





Frame: HiTen Steel


Fork: Rigid Steel


Headset: Steel with bearings


Bars: Steel


Stem: Steel Quill Type


Chainset: Steel


Front Brake: Alloy V Rear


Brake: Alloy V


Rims: Alloy


Front Hub: Steel


Rear Hub: Steel


Tyres: 20 x 1.95 Front, 20 x 1.95 Rear


Seatpost: Steel


"
      ["availableToSell"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["deliverable"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["itemWeight"]=>
      float(20)
      ["typeLkp"]=>
      int(1)
      ["stkBrandId"]=>
      int(136)
      ["dataVatId"]=>
      int(1)
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#4 (10) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(64223)
      ["name"]=>
      string(45) "DiamondBack Accomplice Black 20 Inch BMX 2012"
      ["descrShort"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["descrLong"]=>
      string(1514) "
DiamondBack Accomplice Black 20 Inch BMX 2012 Introduction


If there were laws to prevent us from providing you with pro-level quality in a complete at a suspiciously low price, the new Accomplice would have us doing some hard time. Fortunately for both of us; there aren't. The bike has, however spent some time on the drawing board over the last year. In addition to being cleaned up and simplified, the Accomplice also bolsters a new frame with Affix Bush BB, Affix 9T cassette rear hub, Affix tyres and Butted tapered forks and bars! Built in Germany by the world famous KHE bmx experts.


Specification and Features of DiamondBack Accomplice Black 20 Inch BMX 2012




Diamondback Ambigram CRMO 3 piece crank on Affix Mid Bush BB (red ano) with Affix Orbis Alloy 25T sprocket


Rear U brake with soft compound pad and front caliper brake with alloy hinge levers


Front KHE Big "V" rim on Affix Ting Hub, rear Alienation Black Sheep rim on Affix 9T Hub with Affix 2.1 Tyres


Affix system stem with 2 piece butted handlebar 8" rise 28.8" width


KHE Exhib Project 2 saddle/post combo


Diamondback/KHE collaboration: Full 4130 Butted chromoly BMX frame with integrated head tube and Diamond "X" Brace, with full 4130 butted tapered chromoly BMX forks"


DiamondBack Accomplice Black 20 Inch BMX 2012 is perfect for:




Hitting the parks, jumps or a bit of street riding.

"
      ["availableToSell"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["deliverable"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["itemWeight"]=>
      float(15)
      ["typeLkp"]=>
      int(1)
      ["stkBrandId"]=>
      int(215)
      ["dataVatId"]=>
      int(1)
    }
  }
}
```

Whenever im using the foreach loop I get a error: Invalid Arguement supplied foreach. Im parsing it based on the answer ive just found:
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522572/parsing-stdclass-object-data-in-php)

Comment: Change `->` -> `=>` and also make sure you either pass an object or and array to foreach. [RTM](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Thanks il give it a Try @Rizier123

Comment: And also thanks to the person who commented before im trying that now

Comment: Sorry it's deleted. but try what @Rizier123 said.

Comment: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '(' ** Thats the message ive just got from using "=>"

Comment: Its okay I got the arguements the wrong way around like you said @anant kumar singh, thanks...

Comment: Welcome man:):) you can voteup comment also if its useful

Comment: How? Im new to stack overflow :)